# Algolia React InstantSearch: How to filter based on 2 similar parameters?

Tags: algolia, react-instantsearch

Hopefully the title is clear, but I have a scenario where I have 2 price range slider fields that a user can search on, Sale Price and Lease Price. I need to return results in which the item can fall in between *either* price range. I've defined the `operator="or"` but it doesn't seem to do anything. It appears to be doing an AND selection, so items from Algolia that are within both price ranges return.

What do I need to do to get this to work?

I have two of these components on the page, one for Sale Price and one for Lease Price.

```
<ReactSlider
        className="price-slider"
        value={[range.min, range.max]}
        disabled={disabled}
        markClassName="slider-mark"
        min={min}
        max={max}
        operator="or"
        pearling
        minDistance={minDistance}
        withTracks
        snapDragDisabled={false}
        ariaLabel={['Lower thumb', 'Upper thumb']}
        ariaValuetext={state => `Slider value ${state.valueNow}`}
        thumbClassName="slider-thumb"
        trackClassName="slider-track"
        renderThumb={renderThumb}
        onAfterChange={onChange}
        onSliderClick={onSliderClick}
      />
```

Each one outputs a slider:

[image]

The request query that it generates:

```
shop?page=1&configure[hitsPerPage]=18&range[sh_sale_price][min]=14680&range[sh_sale_price][max]=119012&range[sh_lease_price][min]=7347&range[sh_lease_price][max]=49972
```

Comment: do you have a logic for building the query?

Comment: Nothing custom, the instantsearch components are building the query.